# Checking if NSArray contains block

Tags: objective-c

Is it safe to check for the existence of particular block within NSArray? Let's say we have this code:

```
int (^blockA)(int) = ^(int x) {
  return x;
};

int (^blockB)(int) = ^(int x) {
  return x;
};

NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[blockA copy], [blockB copy], nil];

if ([array containsObject:blockA]) {
  NSLog(@"Idx: %d", [array indexOfObject:blockA]);
}

if ([array containsObject:blockB]) {
  NSLog(@"Idx: %d", [array indexOfObject:blockB]);
}
```

The output I get is:

```
Idx: 0 
Idx: 1
```

So it appears to be working, but I'm not sure why, especially because array contains copies of original blocks whose implementation is identical. Does each block has some internal identifier or what? Elaboration on why this works would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

blockA and [blockA copy] will usually not be the same object, so [array containsObject:blockA] will be unlikely to return YES. You'd have to write for example blockA = [blockA copy] *before* you add it to the array.

Comment: yes, Block_copy() or the `copy` method moves the Block to the heap from stack.

Answer (score 0):

The `containsObject:` method of `NSArray` compares using `isEqual:`, it doesn't check for pointer equality. isEqual also works for blocks as you can see in this example:

```
void (^block)(void) = ^{
    NSLog(@"Some Block");
};

__typeof(block) b = [block copy];

NSLog(@"%i", [b isEqual:block]);
```

this will print `1`.

Comment: Yeah, I see it works, but I'm interested in why. What does isEqual: do in case of blocks? Obviously it's not checking only implementation.